# Open Windows Explorer UnFocused

Tags: vb.net

I am using `Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select,""" & ExcelPath & """")` to open Windows Explorer and also select an Excel file. This always brings Explorer to the front\focused. I would like for explorer to open unfocused.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is minimized and option?

Comment: yes, that is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Process.StartInfo.WindowStyle` allows you to start the given window minimised or hidden. Sample code:

```
Dim curProcess As Process = New Process()
With curProcess
    With .StartInfo
        .FileName = "explorer.exe"
        .Arguments = "/select," & """" & ExcelPath & """"
        .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized 'ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    End With
    .Start()
End With
```

Comment: This works, with one exception. the .Arguments part isn't working, cause it is opening in the My Documents folder. ExcelPath is a misleading variable name. It is actually the file's full name (directory\file name). How can this be tweeked to open the explorer minimized and also have the file selected\highlighted?  Thanks for your help in advance varocarbas!!

Comment: @JoeB Actually, there wasn't any typo (I prefer to set the quotes "outside the string" and that's why I quickly assumed that might be a typo (because I trusted your "it does not work") but tested my previous version (identical to your original code, by the way) and actually worked fine). Why are you saying that the file is not being highlighted? This code (and the previous one) works exactly as your original code (but by minimising the window).

Comment: You're correct, no typo. I was trying to use ExcelPath before it was assigned the actual path. Thanks for your help! One more question....is it possible to have the explorer size equal to the screen (maximized) while also having it minimized?

Comment: @JoeB No problem. You are asking for too much, don't you think? :) It seems that this property does only accept one value (maximised or minimised); if you want to perform further changes on an external window you would have to rely on API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old but I came across it looking for a way to open windows explorer with the directory maximized as my way was opening minimized in the system tray.I believe this will do what you want: 
 Process.Start("explorer.exe", ExcelPath)

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift you content quality up